# Condition in class body?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have noticed something very unusual with Java class.

If I instantiate a Condition (from a lock) in the class-body, it doesnt instatiate the object. Here is an example:

```
private class ConcurrentQ{
        ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
        Lock writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
        Condition emptyList = readLock.newCondition(); //PROBLEM!
...

}
```

If I did `ConcurrentQ q = new ConcurreqntQ()`, it would not instantiate, but if removed the `//PROBLEM!` line it works fine.

Can I know why?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock.html#newCondition--)?

Comment: @shmosel, I'm sorry, I didn't and I should have. How can I use conditions then with `ReadWriteLocks`?

Comment: Re, "... it would not instantiate" It might be helpful if you would include the text of any error messages in your question.

Comment: You can create a condition on the write lock.

Comment: @besmirched, literally nothing happens! It just ends the process without doing anything

Comment: `new ConcurrentQ()` can't do _nothing_. It's either going to return a reference to a newly created `ConcurrentQ` instance, or else it's going to throw an exception.  If it throws an exception, then there's going to be a message unless,... Did you write code that would catch the exception and ignore it?

Comment: That code throws an UnsupportedOperationException. If you aren't seeing the stack trace then something is either catching the exception or suppressing the output.

Comment: Here is the javadoc for ReentrantReadWriteLock#newCondition: `/**
         * Throws {@code UnsupportedOperationException} because
         * {@code ReadLocks} do not support conditions.
         *
         * @throws UnsupportedOperationException always
         */`

Comment: @neildo, why dont readlocks support conditions?

Comment: Conditions are generally used to signal a change to the underlying resource which should only happen under the thread with write lock. Why do you want to use the read lock to create the condition?

Comment: @neildo, I explained it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339476/conditions-in-read-write-locks?noredirect=1#comment91626204_52339476, essentially because I want to have a  `peek()` method in concurrent queue

Answer (score 0):

The Condition class provides the ability for a thread to wait for some condition to occur while executing the critical section.

This can occur when a thread acquires the access to the critical section but doesn’t have the necessary condition to perform its operation. For example, a reader thread can get access to the lock of a shared queue, which still doesn’t have any data to consume.

For a Writer thread:
The write lock provides a Condition implementation that behaves in the same way, with respect to the write lock, as the Condition implementation provided by ReentrantLock newCondition does for ReentrantLock.
The Condition can, of course, only be used with the write lock. The read lock does not support a Condition and readLock().newCondition() throws Unsupported OperationException.

Hope this hepls....