# Conditions in Read/Write Locks

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, since `ReadLocks` cannot have conditions, what is the proper way to use conditions between `Read/Write locks`?

Here is my concurrent queue class:

```
private class ConcurrentQ{
        ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
        Lock writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
        Condition emptyList = writeLock.newCondition();
        Queue<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

        /* */
        public void push(int x, int thread){
            try{
                writeLock.lock();
                list.offer(x);
                emptyList.signalAll();
            } catch (Exception ex){
            } finally {
                writeLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        //Must look at empty case
        public void pop(int thread){
            int val = -1;
            try{
                writeLock.lock();
                val = list.poll();
            } catch (Exception e){
            } finally {
                writeLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void peek(int thread){
            int val = -2;
            try{
                readLock.lock();
                while(list.isEmpty())
                    emptyList.await(); //////PROBLEM HERE!
                val = list.peek();
            }  catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                readLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a problem here. Since `ReadLock` cannot have conditions, I added a condition in the `WriteLock` BUT I cannot call it inside a block where I am using `readLock.lock() ... readLock.unlock()` so what can I do? In my `peek()` method I want to wait if the `list` is empty.

Thanks

Comment: How is this question different from your [recent previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339070/condition-in-class-body)?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, can you explain how you find it even close to same? There is literally nothing similar between the questions...

Comment: Why do you think that ReadWriteLock fits well here? See for example https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java

Comment: @algrid, Actually, I believe it does fit. We can have 1,000,000 threads do a peek() so readlock is useful here, but only 1 can offer/poll at a time so thats why I believe readwritelock is useful